# Are the legendaries Prince Malchezaar adds to my deck all different?

Tags: hearthstone

Are the 5 legendary minions which Prince Malchezaar adds to my deck all different or can two or even more be the same minion? Can I e.g. rely on Reno to heal me up?

[image: Prince Malchezaar]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Prince Malchezaar follows the Deckbuildung rules, which means that

- no legendary that is already in your deck is added
- five differerent legendaries are added
- no legendaries of other classes are added

[Source](http://www.hearthpwn.com/forums/hearthstone-general/card-discussion/166370-new-legendary-card-prince-malchezaar?comment=21)

As @CobaltZorch mentioned in the comments, Prince Malchezaar adds the cards after the mulligan. This makes it possible that a legendary that you already have in your hand is added to the deck. The legendaries in your deck will stil be unique though, so Reno etc. will still work without surprises.

Comment: Small note, he can add legendaries you have in hand, as they aren't in your deck.  I got hit today by a very unexpected and game losing Alexstrazsa double from a warrior.

Comment: @CobaltZorch Are you sure about that? His effect triggers before any cards are drawn, so this should not be possible.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but the cards are added after mulligan, so you have the original 3/4 cards in hand before Malchezaar procs and adds the extra 5

Comment: @CobaltZorch Just tried it, you are right, the cards are added after the starting hands are drawn. Gonna add it to my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Prince Malchezaar will not add duplicate legendaries to your deck, so it is safe to play Reno in your deck. It will also only add neutral and the same class legendaries to you deck.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/4vm13p/reveal_2_new_cards_revealed_by_ben_brode_in_s/ (Reddit post about Ben Brode announcing the card)